# Retrieve Firebase data and fill a model for a listview with Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I use a Firebase database to create an Android chat application using Kotlin.
I want to retrieve the Users and display them in a listview.
The db structure is like this:
[image]
And my method to display the users is:

```
private fun displayUsers(){
val firebaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

    adapterUsers = object : FirebaseListAdapter<Users>(
    this,
    Users::class.java,
    R.layout.user_item,
    firebaseReference){
        override fun populateView(v: View, model: Users, position: Int)
        {
            val UserName = v.findViewById<View>(R.id.user_name) as TextView
            val UserSurname = v.findViewById<View>(R.id.user_surname) as TextView

            UserName.text = model.userName
            UserSurname.text = model.userSurname
        }
    }
    list_with_users.adapter = adapterUsers
}
```

I use a model like this one:

```
data class Users(
    val userName: String? = "Name1",
    val userSurname: String? = "Surname1")
```

It works fine, but the result on the screen is 3 items without user information from the database, but what is displayed is the default model values:
[image]

My question is, how does the model is filled?

Comment: So you want to display the name and surname of your users, right? In this case, please add the `users` node.

Comment: If you want at some point to try [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to can create a functional [Chat App using Kotlin](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

Comment: @AlexMamo exactly! I can use a DataSnapshot somehow but I want to do it with the model way. Where to add the users node?

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks for the tutorial, I will check it

Comment: Edit your question and it in the same way you added the other one.

Comment: @AlexMamo which one? can you clarify a bit more?

Comment: I cannot see anywhere the name and surname in your schema.

Comment: @AlexMamo The name and the surnname are in the root node as one string. Where the User1 and User2 ect is. This code is not final, I am just trying to understad how the model is filled